# What are `optimistic updates` in front-end development

Tags: design-patterns

I'm reading the [intro to `redux` pattern](https://redux.js.org/introduction/motivation), and there is the following paragraph there:

> ... consider the new requirements becoming common in front-end product
> development, such as handling optimistic updates, rendering on the
> server, fetching data before performing route transitions, and so on.

My question is what is meant by *optimistic updates* here?

Comment: Example right here: when clicking the up or downvote arrow, the UI reflects the vote immediately, even if the server hasn't successfully processed it yet. The vote will actually be rolled back with an error message if the server fails.

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17514/should-we-be-optimistic-or-pessimistic-with-ui-updates-on-ajax-requests

Comment: @deceze, thanks, yeah, that's the good example.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the link, I'll read through it.

Comment: @deceze I wonder how much of the upvotes for this question are from people testing to see the behavior described in your comment in action :). Mine definitely is!

Answer (score 150, accepted):

In an optimistic update the UI behaves as though a change was successfully completed before receiving confirmation from the server that it actually was - it is being optimistic that it will eventually get the confirmation rather than an error. This allows for a more responsive user experience.