# Should I update the local data model before db confirmation or not?

Tags: json, data-loss

Most of the times when I have to add or update some data, I do two things. Firstly, I send a request to the database to make the addition or update. Secondly, I locally update the data model in the browser for a more seamless experience... instead of waiting to load the entire data again. However, someone has pointed out that this is not good because if there is a network error that prevents the data from being saved or updated in the backend, it will be in contradiction with the local data set which will have already been updated. So the person has suggested that I just wait for the data from the database to be loaded. This way, according to him, the data in the browser and the database will always be in sync.

Honestly, his approach doesn't sound right to me. Because it will introduce delays and not provide a seamless experience. But should I do as he says?

Comment: The pattern you are describing (of updating the UI before confirmation from the database) tends to be referred to as [optimistic updating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009657/what-is-optimistic-updates-in-front-end-development), and it definitely has its uses. You just have to make sure that you can revert the changes if there's an error, so stuff doesn't get out of sync.

Comment: Another relevant link: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17514/should-we-be-optimistic-or-pessimistic-with-ui-updates-on-ajax-requests