# React usage in Facebook comment

Tags: reactjs, facebook-comments

I am learning react.js. I am trying to develop an application where there is a feature like Facebook comment system.I would like to know "is Facebook comment coming from Database using AJAX request or it is placing text just from input box using React.js.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Facebook comment reply is so fast. On the other hand in my application I can't make is fast like Facebook.

Comment: You can give this a shot, could be helpful - https://pusher.com/tutorials/live-comments-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

Both. I think they are using [optimistic UI update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009657/what-is-optimistic-updates-in-front-end-development) and at the same time update the database with ajax. Only when there is an error with request UI will show that this comment was not successfully committed.

Comment: Does Meta still maintain dedicated iOS and Android engineering teams in addition to their central React Native cross-platform team? Or has
the organization shifted more resources directly into React Native as the main mobile development focus?
Beyond the open-source React Native framework, does Meta leverage any proprietary or in-house cross-platform libraries/tools?
Are certain performance-critical parts of the app still native, while other components like the marketplace section may be React Native?