# How is the clientMutationId used for optimistic updates in front ends?

Tags: ruby, graphql, relay, graphql-ruby

I was reading about GraphQL mutations and had to decide wether to use Relay mutations or not in graphql-ruby. I stumbled upon the `clientMutationId` here https://graphql-ruby.org/api-doc/1.8.5/GraphQL/Schema/RelayClassicMutation.html

`clientMutationId` apparently is used for optimistic updates (found here [what is `optimistic updates` in front-end development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009657/what-is-optimistic-updates-in-front-end-development)), but I'm unsure how this is intended to be used.

It seems that you pass the `clientMutationId` along with your mutation, and the server returns this value in the response. But what's the purpose of this? Some kind of client-side idempotency?