# Updating State of a component before request finishes

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-redux, auth0

More of an implementation question. I have an application which allow users to bookmark specific pages. In order to bookmark a page, the users must be logged in. Whenever a request is made, we check to see if their current token has expired. If it is, we re-authorize through auth0 and then send the request to our backend.

When the request is complete, we then update the state of the bookmark icon to be filled in, informing the user that the page is now bookmarked.

This process of calling out to auth0 takes about 1.5-2 seconds, sometimes causing a noticeable delay after clicking the icon.

My initial thought was I would update the state of the bookmark on the frontend first, then send the request to the backend to actually persist it, and then assuming the request failed, would update the state again to undo the first change. This would guarantee that the update would always "appear" instantaneous from the users perspective.

However, part of me is feeling like this isn't a proper solution. Just hoping if someone could weigh in and let me know if this is a good way to approach this problem.

Comment: This is just fine, it's called an [optimistic update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009657/what-is-optimistic-updates-in-front-end-development).

Comment: Perfect, appreciate the link for additional info. Thanks. (Feel free to leave an answer to the question so I can marked you as the solution).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is \`optimistic updates\` in front-end development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009657/what-is-optimistic-updates-in-front-end-development)